# Gradle - exclude dependencies from pom file

Tags: gradle, build-dependencies

I have a project that I build with Gradle (project 'A'). Another project (project 'B') uses project A as a dependency. In project A there are dependencies, but project B does not need some of them.

I need to exclude those dependencies in project B but I don't want B to have to be aware of the list of dependencies to exclude. So I want to do that in A.

I was looking for a way to exclude dependencies from the A pom file, which will give me what I need, but did not find how to do that.

Comment: According to _"In project A there are dependencies, but project B does not need some of them."_ it sounds like these _"redundant"_ dependencies are not needed for the compilation of project B. Is it possible that these are not needed for the compilation of project A as well but only for testing? In this case you should add these dependencies to the `testCompile` configuration.

Comment: I guess I oversimplified the use case - I have two uses for A as an artifact, one with all the dependencies and the other with a subset. So in any case, I will have two artifacts that can be created from this project. But for A to build I need all the dependencies. If I find a solution, I will put a condition in the build file based on the Jenkins environment, that will control if a dependency is written to the pom file. The goal is avoid bringing all the unneeded dependencies and inflate the project B war/uber-jar, without having to split A to two different projects.